# How to build a screen canvas?

Tags: home-theater

In my new apartment I have a lot of space and therefore I want to use a projector to watch TV and movies. Unfortunately, professional screen canvas are very expensive. So I plan to build one by myself.

The silver screen should have 3.20 meter width and 1.80 height. How can I do that? What material should I use to build the screen? How expensive will it be?

Comment: You mention the wall has huge windows -- does that mean you're trying to build a screen that retracts? Do you have something in mind for that mechanism already?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment, do you mean if I plan to build a mobile canvas or a fixed one?

Comment: Many projection screens (like [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10829&cs_id=1082901&p_id=3015&seq=1&format=2), for example), are mounted to the ceiling, and can be pulled down (some manually, some motorized) when needed, and otherwise stay out of the way. I'm asking if that's your intent, or if you would want to build something portable, or if you'd build some kind of temporary structure with a screen on it that blocks your windows all the time, but can be disassembled/moved when you move out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your heart is not set on a **silver** screen, I had good results using blackout cloth - this is white, rubber-impregnated cloth that is used for curtains.  I got a swath that was 48 inches wide - 1.21 meters, so a bit smaller than what you're looking for, but the largest they had available at the fabric shop.  By using a single swath, I avoided seams in the screen.  I made a 2.35:1 screen, so the final result was about 117cm x 275cm, which is really the largest screen my room could have handled.

I built a wood frame, stretched the fabric over it, and stapled it in place.  Four years later, it still looks great, and the total cost was under $100.

Answer (score 4):

You can buy projector screen paint, and just paint your screen on the wall. I don't have personal experience with it, but here's [one example](http://www.paintonscreen.com/) -- $179 for 1 gallon which looks to be more than enough for your screen.

I'd also recommend trying your projector on a white wall before doing anything -- you may find it to be acceptable without investing in any kind of screen.  I have seen this done where I work and it looked surprisingly good although your results will vary depending on the brightness of your projector and the ambient light in the room.  If you like the results you could make your "screen" look a little less low-budget by framing it with casing trim.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not an option since the wall I want to project against has some huge windows.